# Get pimcore snippet name from view / controller

Tags: php, view, controller, pimcore

Im using Pimcore's snippet in that way:

```
<?php echo $this->snippet("mySnippet"); ?>
```

How can I get the name of the snippet ("mySnippet") from the view / controller?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the name of the snippet editable is a bit harder task, because the embedded snippet is not given any knowledge of its container (see the source file `/pimcore/models/Document/Tag/snippet.php`). The best solution I can think of (a bit ugly though) is to pass the name down to the snippet as a parameter, like this:

```
<?php echo $this->snippet("mySnippet", array("snippetName" => "mySnippet")); ?>
```

And then in the snippet view get the value of this parameter:

```
<?php echo $this->request->snippetName; ?>
```

Another approach is to edit the source file of Pimcore to automatically pass down the name, but remember this might cause problems when updating to a new version of Pimcore. But if you want to use this approach, add the following to the file `/pimcore/models/Document/Tag/snippet.php`:

```
$params["snippetName"] = $this->name;
```

just below the line `$params["document"] = $this->snippet;` in the function `frontend()`. (In pimcore 2.1.0 this would be line 91)

Comment: I think you missed the point. I need to get the value "mySnippet" from the view of the snippet. in other words, get the name of itself.

When im using `$this->document->key` inside snippet view im getting the document key and not the snippet name.

Comment: Oh, yes I misunderstood the question. That is a bit harder, but I gave you a possible workaround in the updated answer.

Comment: Also added an alternative solution to edit the Pimcore source to always pass the name to the snippet when embedding.